# Excel VBA rows comparison based on condition

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

In Excel I am having my data as below, I need a VBA code to get the result

```
ItemId  Name    Type    RecId
100     AA      Iron        1
100     AB      Plastic     2
101     BB      Iron        1
101     BB      Iron        2
102     CC      Iron        1
102     CC      Iron        1
103     DD      Iron        1
104     DD      Plastic     2

Result should be
ItemId  Name    Type    RecId
100     AA      Iron        1 (should be highlighted, ItemId 100 Different - here Name is different)
100     AB      Plastic     2
101     BB      Iron        1       
101     BB      Iron        2
102     CC      Iron        1
102     CC      Iron        1
103     DD      Iron        1 (should be highlighted, ItemId 103 Different - here Type is different)
103     DD      Plastic     2
```

my need is to compare and highlight based on RecId 1 and 2 for each ItemId, 
ItemId 101 and 102 should not be higlighted as it is identical and RecId are 1

Comment: Why not use condiional formatting?

Comment: It's probably doable with conditional formatting

Comment: I need to automate the sheet with thousands of rows, that is the reason I need VBA to acheive this

Comment: Then try to map out a process by first doing it by hand. Once you know the necessary steps, you can start to automate (and generalize) them. A decent starting point is recording a macro of the manual process you found out. If you get stuck with adapting that macro, you can come back here and ask a question about the specific problem you have with it.

Comment: Writing a conditional rule and applying to thousands of rows takes just a few minutes.

Comment: Just be aware that you won't get around learning some VBA in the process. Asking questions on SO won't alleviate that need. (Rather the opposite, I'd say.)

Comment: I don't have much knowledge on excel, could you please guide me how to apply conditional rule

Comment: Just google "conditional formatting" and give it try you'll figure it out.

Comment: Google will give you links to hundreds of guides on conditional formatting. Searching stackoverflow will give you a myriad of questions (+answers) on the general topic. Most questions an Excel beginner will likely have are probably already answered at least once.

Answer (score 1):

***Building conditional formatting rules is quite easy, and you can find lots of examples on the internet. But I'm on a good mood ;) ***

First make a basic rule for you first line of data. Select the cells to highlight, then click on "Home"->"Conditional Formatting"->"New Rule"
[image]

Select "Use a formula ..." and input your formula (Here, you want to check against next row, so we will use `=AND($A2=$A3,OR($B2<>$B3,$C2<>$C3))` ) and choose your highlighting format by clicking on the "Format..." button, then click OK.

[image]

Your "Conditional formatting" applies only to the first row of data by now, but you can edit the range easily: Go Back to "Home"->"Conditional formatting"->"Manage rules"

[image]

and change the "Applies to" range.

[image]

You can even use dynamic named ranges or indirect formulas in the "Applies to" range box.

Comment: I'm trying to apply your conditional formula in the below code, can you help me

Comment: @raajesh the point of using conditional formatting is that you don't need any VBA code at all.